# A fail concerning the expression @autoreleasepool

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsautoreleasepool

I downloaded a sample code from developer.apple.com  called  [SimpleGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleGestureRecognizers/Listings/Classes_GestureRecognizerViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009460-Classes_GestureRecognizerViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_4) and in the main.m the program send a fail, because the program does not know the expression @auoreleasepool

The fail is: Unexpected '@' in program.
I searched on the internet, if there is a same problem happens to someone, but there was nobody having the same problem.

Do you know, why this program does not know the expression @autoreleasepool?
My Xcode version is 3.2.6

Thank you for your help and presumptions in forward

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`@autoreleasepool` was introduced in [LLVM 3.0](http://llvm.org/releases/3.0/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#subproj), the compiler available in Xcode 4.2. Since you’re using Xcode 3.2.6, you have LLVM 1.6 and GCC, neither of which recognises that directive.

You can change the code to use `NSAutoreleasePool` instead of `@autoreleasepool` so that it builds with Xcode 3.2.6. For example, replace:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    …
}
```

with:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
…
[pool drain];
```